# Base View Page in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

On ASP.NET MVC 5 I used a base ViewPage with a few properties:

```
public String PageTitle { get; set; }
public String PageDescription { get; set; }
public String[] BodyCssClasses { get; set; }
```

Then on each view I would have:

```
@{
  PageTitle = "Title ..."
  PageDescription" = "Description ..."
  BodyCssClasses = new String[] { "main", "home" }
}
```

On the master page I would simply use something like:

```
<title>@Title</title>
```

With this approach I was able to use Strong Typed for page properties ...

Is it possible to use a Base View Page in ASP.NET MVC 6?

Since there is no Web.Config how could this be done?

Any suggestions for better options to define page head info is welcome.

**UPDATE**

I followed the suggested and I am using:

```
public abstract class ViewPageBase<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel> {
  public String Title { get; set; }
} // ViewPageBase
```

Then on _ViewImports I have:

```
@inherits ViewPageBase<TModel>
```

On _Layout.cshtml I have:

```
<title>@Title</title>
```

And finally on a view which uses that layout I have:

```
@{
  Title = "Page Title";
  Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Everything compiles and runs but the page title is always empty.

Does anyone has any idea why?

Comment: FYI - Actually, there is a web.config file under the `wwwroot` folder. However, I don't believe you can use it to configure a base view page like you could before. As far as I can tell, it is strictly to configure IIS.

Comment: Yes, that was what I found. It would be nice to Stiller be abre to set the title and other page properties without using viewbag or view model.

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, what happens if you just change the name of the variable/property `Title` to anything else?

Answer (score 5):

The technique you have described in your update will technically work.

Unfortunately, as @Peter notes, you get one instance of your custom ViewPage for the view, and a different instance for the layout.  Because you are using two different instances, you cannot set a property on the view and expect to access that property on the layout.  **That's the answer to your updated question:**

> Everything compiles and runs but the page title is always empty. Does
> anyone has any idea why?

@Peter has offered a work around using the `ViewBag`.  I'd like to offer an additional workaround using dependency injection.

For instance, consider placing your custom properties in their own class, with its own interface:

```
public interface IPageMetaData {
    string PageTitle { get; set; }
    string PageDescription { get; set; }
    string[] BodyCssClasses { get; set; }
}

public class PageMetaData : IPageMetaData {
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageDescription { get; set; }
    public string[] BodyCssClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Now, register this with the .Net Core dependency injection framework.  Use the `Scoped` lifecycle, so only one instance will be created per-web request.  In a vanilla project, this takes place in `Startup.cs`, in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IPageMetaData, PageMetaData>();
}
```

Finally, update your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file to inject this object into your views:

```
@inject Your.Namespace.Goes.Here.IPageMetaData MetaData;
```

Now your views will have a ambient `MetaData` property that will correspond to a per-web request instance of the `PageMetaData` class.  You can access it from both views and from the layout:

```
@{
    // In a view
    MetaData.PageTitle = "Set a page title";
}

@* In a layout *@
<title>@MetaData.PageTitle</title>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to make your base view page inherit from `RazorPage`.

```
public abstract class ViewPageBase<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
}
```

Then you should be able to configure all your pages to inherit from this in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

```
@inherits ViewPageBase<TModel>
```

**UPDATE**

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I wonder if you could use the common ViewBag to share data between your View and the Layout.

Back the properties in your base page class with the ViewBag:

```
public abstract class ViewPageBase<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return ViewBag.Title; }
        set { ViewBag.Title = value; }
    }
}
```

Set the property in your view:

```
@{
    Title = "Home Page"; 
}
```

Use the property in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@Title</title>
```

Comment: I followed your approach but I the property I set does not show. I just added an Update to my question. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I think the issue is that there are two separate instances of your page class created - one for the view and one for the layout - so the property you set in one is not available in the other. I've updated my answer with a workaround that uses the shared ViewBag.

Comment: Out of curiousity, did this approach work in MVC5 - setting properties in your view and accessing them in you layout/master page? I haven't had a chance to test it ...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the `@inherits` Razor directive.

For instance:

`@inherits MyBaseViewPage`

Comment: Please, see the update I added on my question ... I wonder why this is not working.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug with MVC/Razor. Hah, it should definitely work :)

Comment: Note: This was fixed for the upcoming beta8 release.

Comment: But what if we have view(s) in a portable class library, do we have to put same `_viewImports` in all these modules :))?.It should have been done in a more clean way. eg: DependencyInjection.for example shouldn't it?