# MVC 6 - Dropdown in header, value accessible from all controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Quite new to MVC and I've hit a bit of a stumbling block with what I thought would be very straight forward.

I have a partial _Header view within my _Layout. In here, I want to display a dropdown with a list of items that is populated based on the logged in user.

Within each controller in my project, I want to retrieve the selected value and display data dependent on this.

I've tried several attempts but keep getting stuck in different positions. I was going down the route of creating a base controller to hold my list of items and selected item value (both static). Then, in my AccountController I can populate these values on login. I'm fine with accessing all this from my other controllers... but how do I populate the dropdown list in my _Header? I don't seem to have access to these. Am I even going down the proper route? In classic ASP I would have stored these in viewstate..

**UPDATE - with Marco's suggestion**

The viewbag value set from the controller is not available in the views (although accessible) - it just always returns null. I've changed the select list to a simple int for the moment just to keep things simpler. Code below

ViewPageBase -

```
public abstract class ViewPageBase : RazorPage
{
    public int SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (ViewBag.SelectedValue == null ? 0 : ViewBag.SelectedValue); }
        set { ViewBag.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
}

public abstract class ViewPageBase<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    public int SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (ViewBag.SelectedValue == null ? 0 : ViewBag.SelectedValue); }
        set { ViewBag.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
}
```

BaseController -

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public int SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (ViewBag.SelectedValue == null ? 0 : ViewBag.SelectedValue); }
        set { ViewBag.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
}
```

AccountController : BaseController -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            SelectedValue = 10;
            _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
            return View("Lock");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

_Layout -

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Header"); }
```

Within _Header, I am just trying to read @SelectedValue but this is always null (0 in my case since I'm doing a null check).

Comment: You can get data into your _Layout (and thus the header) via `ViewBag`.  Alternatively you can have your _Header as a partial action (rather than a partial view) in which case it will be calling a controller and can get any data it needs then.

Comment: *"in my AccountController I can populate these values on **login**"* - that's now how stateless MVC controller-actions work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach

1. Add a HTML dropdown in your partial view.
2. Write a function which make an ajax call and get the values and bind your dropdown with these values using jquery. It should hit server when page is loaded(document.ready).
3. Now add a change event to your dropdown and on every change make an ajax call and set the selected value on session.
4. So now you will be having these selected value on every controller until you have session exist.

I think this help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom razor view base class from which all your views will inherit. Here is the article on how it's done:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/

Basically you will make a class which inherits from WebViewPage. In this class you will declare a property that will hold your select list:

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    private SelectList _mySelectList;

    public SelectList MySelectList
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                _mySelectList = (SelectList)ViewBag.MySelectList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _mySelectList = null;
            }
            return _mySelectList;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    private SelectList _mySelectList;

    public SelectList MySelectList
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                _mySelectList = (SelectList)ViewBag.MySelectList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _mySelectList = null;
            }
            return _mySelectList;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the value for the select list in this case is being retrieved from the ViewBag. It does not have to be but this was the easiest for me to demonstrate the idea. You can set the value for your view bag inside the base controller that you made. Now every view will have access to this property.

The only thing left for you to do is tell your solution to construct MVC views using your new class. You can do this by adding the following line to your web config:

```
<pages pageBaseType="Project.Namespace.Views.CustomWebViewPage">
```

where Project.Namespace.Views is the namespace where your new custom class is located. Please note that this line sits inside the

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```

tag and it needs to be added to all web.configs that are related to your views - web.configs inside the Views folders.

Once all of this is done you can simply do:

```
@MySelectList
```

within your view to access your select list. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I've tried this however the ViewBag values don't seem to get across and I always get null's. As I'm using MVC6, I've amended your suggestion in line with the solution described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563279/base-view-page-in-asp-net-mvc-6. This works in that I can access the value from all Views but if I set the value from within my Account Controller it still appears as null in my View.

Comment: @xemmers Is your account controller inheriting from your base controller?

Comment: @Marco yes, the ViewBag value is being set within the basecontroller and all controllers inherit this. but just appears as null within the views. I can see the value being set correctly within the controllers and can also retrieve this value from other controllers since its static and that's correct. To be clear, in the BaseController I should just be setting ViewBag.whatever correct?

Comment: @xemmers You have to set the value of ViewBag.MySelectList to your SelectList. It has to be of type SelectList because if you look at my code in the try catch block I'm trying to cast the view bag into a SelectList. If you're setting the view bag value to some object that is not of type SelectList then it obviously will not work... and try catch will suppress any errors...

Comment: @Marco - I'm actually just trying with an int to eliminate any of those issues. I've updated the original question with my code.